# IIS Redirect with Form Submit Data

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis

I am having a form Submit using the following JavaScript code:

```js
var strDoc = 
  "<html>\n<body>\n" +
    "<form action='http://localhost:9000/First.aspx' method='post' name='form1'>\n" + 
      "<input type='hidden' value='Rahul' name='USER'><input type='hidden' value='WC' name='UserType'>\n" + 
    "</form>\n</body>\n</html>";

var Login = window.self;
Login.document.open();
Login.document.write(strDoc);
Login.document.close();
Login.document.form1.submit();
```

The Action URL is then redirected using the following Redirection rule in IIS:

```xml
<rule name="TestRewdirect">
  <match url="First.aspx" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="Second.aspx" />
</rule>
```

The redirection rule works, but the problem is with data on Form submit. That data is lost during the redirect.

I don't even have a file with named `First.aspx`.

I cannot change anything on client side, because that is different project. I can only change on server side.

So how can I redirect the form with submitted data?

Comment: Why not store the data in a session or cookie, I believe that is because of the full postback...